# Proof of Liouville's Theorem for a divergent phase space

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let's consider the autonomous differential equation $x' = f(x) $ with phase space in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and flow function $\phi(t,x)$. Let $K$ be an invariant set in the phase space.

According to the version of Liouville's theorem I am currently trying to come to terms with, it holds for any $A \subset K$ that
$$ \frac{d}{dt} m(\phi(t,A)) = \iint_{\phi(t,A)} \text{div} f(x) \text{d}x,$$ where $m$ is the $n$-dimensional Lebesgue measure.

The proof I am trying to understand uses [Liouville's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_formula) to show for any $h \in \mathbb{R}$ that
$$m(\phi(t+h,A)) = \iint_{\phi(t,A)} \exp \left( \int_0^h (\text{div} f)(\phi(s,x)) \text{d}s \right) \text{d}x,$$

which seems straightforward. It follows quite obviously that
$$ \frac{m(\phi(t+h,A)) - m(\phi(t,A))}{h} = \frac{1}{h} \iint_{\phi(t,A)} \left[ \exp \left( \int_0^h (\text{div} f)(\phi(s,x)) \text{d}s \right) - 1 \right] \text{d}x.$$

We know that $$f(x) = \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \phi(t,x) |_{t=0}~~~~ \text{and   }~~ \text{div} f(x) = \text{trace}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x),$$ and from Liouville's formula we get
$$ \exp \left( \int_0^h (\text{div} f)(\phi(s,x)) \text{d}s \right) = \text{det} \left( 
 \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x} (h,x) \right). $$ My question is, how do we get from here to
$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{m(\phi(t+h,A)) - m(\phi(t,A))}{h} = \iint_{\phi(t,A)} \text{div} f(x) \text{d}x ~~\text{?}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are comfortable moving the limit under the integral sign (which can be done with mild hypotheses on $f$), then you have

$$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{m(\phi(t+h,A))-m(\phi(t,A))}{h} = \iint_{\phi(t,A)}\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{1}{h}\left[\exp\left(\int_0^h(\text{div} f)(\phi(s,x))ds\right)-1\right]dx$$

Considering the limit definition of the derivative, the limit under the integral sign is exactly

$$\frac{d}{dt}\exp\left(\int_0^{t} (\text{div}f)(\phi(s,x))ds\right)\bigg\vert_{t=0} $$

But we can calculate this derivative using the chain rule and fundamental theorem of calculus as

$$\begin{align}\frac{d}{dt}\exp\left(\int_0^{t} (\text{div}f)(\phi(s,x))ds\right)\bigg\vert_{t=0} &=(\text{div}f)(\phi(t,x))\exp\left(\int_0^{t} (\text{div}f)(\phi(s,x))ds\right)\bigg\vert_{t=0} \\ &= (\text{div} f)(\phi(0,x))\exp\left(\int_0^{0} (\text{div}f)(\phi(s,x))ds\right)\\
&=(\text{div} f)(x)\end{align}$$

In the last line, we used that a flow $\phi(x,t)$ is the identity for $t=0$.